# Display data in a table in Universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have been looking for a couple of days for a UWP control that has similar functionality as the WPF ListView, which allows me to create a table like appearance.

Is there a control like this in the UWP or not?

What I want to achieve is a SCRUM and Kanban overview for Jira Software. Maybe there are better options.

Comment: Most makers of 3rd party controls for UWP have a datagrid control.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has created an add-on control that fits this use case nicely, the DataGrid control from their community toolkit.

More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid

It supports sorting, filtering, grouping, and can even generate columns automatically from supplied data.

Comment: This looks exactly what I needed back then, thanks for the late answer. The project is dead by now, cause I am on Linux and youtrack for development now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a control such as that and it is called listview.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx

Maybe you could use GridView as well, there is a nice short tutorial on:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-040-Data-Binding-to-the-GridView-and-ListView-Controls

Comment: Neither the ListView nor the GridView give the options like the ListView from WPF ;)